# Create form after index.php&value=1

Tags: javascript, php, css

Hello I have this form code as shown below

```
<td>    
<form action="pay/index.php">           
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
<input type="hidden" value="1.00" name="amount">
</form>
</td>
```

The result is `index.php?amount=1.00`, I want to create
`index.php?amount=1.00&value=1`

How should I add `&value=1` after it?

Comment: add `<input type="hidden" value="1" name="value">`

Comment: What part of the HTML adds the `amount=1.00` in your opinion? And why didn't you just try to replicate it for another form value?

Comment: Fixed Thx.!!!......................<

Answer (score 0):

When you use `method="GET"`, which is the default, all the named inputs become URL parameters. So you just need to add another hidden input with the name `value`.

```
<form action="pay/index.php">           
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="hidden" value="1.00" name="amount">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="value">
</form>
```